# Combine Month name and Year in one column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I need to combine Month name and Year column in one column 'Month-Year' in datetime format (Day,Month,Year).
Been having issues with NaN and data types. Also need to assign default day as 1 for all rows.

Current data types:

```
Month: (O)
Year: float64
```

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Month':["January"," ","December","February"," "," ","March","July"],
'Year':["2020"," ","2017","2015"," "," ","2019","2015"]})
```

Final Dataframe

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try:**

```
df1 = df1.replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True)
df1['Month-Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Month']+ '-'+ df1['Year']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

---

**df1:**

```
    Month       Year    Month-Year
0   January     2020    01/01/2020
1   NaN         NaN     NaN
2   December    2017    01/12/2017
3   February    2015    01/02/2015
4   NaN         NaN     NaN
5   NaN         NaN     NaN
6   March       2019    01/03/2019
7   July        2015    01/07/2015
```

Comment: You can avoid the regex overhead by, ```pd.to_datetime(df1.Month + df1.Year, errors='coerce').dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y").replace("NaT", "")```

Comment: Been getting an error ```can only concatenate str (not "float") to str```. When I convert the columns to ```astype(str)```, not getting the result. Its just a series of numbers

Comment: change the type of year column to object.

Comment: `df['year'] = df['year'].astype(str)` <------ to convert it into string

Answer (score 0):

One thing u could do is Create a column(Month-Integer) such that January to 01, February to 02, and so-on. Then use this column and Year column to create Month-Year Column, then if you want you can delete the (Month-Integer) Column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df1["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1.Month, format='%B', errors='coerce').dt.date
df1.apply(lambda x: x.date.replace(year=int(float(x.Year))) if x.Year!= " " else "",axis=1)
```